# KMS Key Policy wildcard principal

Tags: amazon-kms

I have multiple IAM role (up to 100) required to use this KMS key.
Instead of listing all the IAM role in the KMS key policy. Is there any way I can wildcard or condition it?

```
{
            "Sid": "Enable IAM Role",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a1",
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a2",
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a3"
                ............
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a100"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
}
```

I tried using arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:root or using condition with stringLike, sourceArn,"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a*"

but none of them work.

Would like to ask around if there is any alternative instead of listing all the iam role down?

Comment: Is this in a same-account or cross-account setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will help you

```
{
    "Sid": "Enable IAM Role",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "kms:*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
            "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/a1*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can someone find in the documentation what to use for the "variable name" - in this case "aws:PrincipalArn"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend tagging a look at a tag-based strategy, as this will work quite nicely assuming all of the roles accessing the key are in the same AWS account as the key.

An overview of this approach is below:

1. Enable IAM policies for the key
2. Add a tag to the key
3. Create a managed IAM policy that grants the `kms:...` action(s) that your roles need.
4. Attach the managed policy to your roles

Details are below.

#### Step 1 - Enable IAM policies for the key

To do this, you simply add use the following key policy:

```json
{
  "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
   },
  "Action": "kms:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

This translates to KMS saying "Any IAM user or role can perform any `kms:...` action on this key, **as long as** they have an IAM policy that explicitly gives them permission to perform that action. That IAM policy could be attached directly to a user or role as an inline policy, attached to an IAM Group and inherited by group users, or created as a customer-managed IAM policy and attached to the users, groups, and roles that need it.

See docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam

#### Step 2 - Add a tag to the KMS key

KMS keys, like many AWS resources, allow you to add arbitrary tags (key-value pairs) to the resource. Many (but not all) taggable resources allow you to use tags as the part of a policy condition, and KMS is one such resource.

For example, let's say your key encrypts an S3 bucket. You could tag the key as: key="kms-key-access-tag" value="s3"

#### Step 3 - Create an IAM Managed Policy

Next step is to create an IAM Managed Policy like below:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AliasBasedIAMPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:*:111122223333:key/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/kms-key-access-tag": "s3"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Step 4 - Attach the policy

Now, you just need to attach that policy to any IAM user, role, or group to give them access to the key.

### Other Recommendations

#### Security

Attribute-based approaches like tags are awesome timesavers and great ways to simplify operations and reduce risk *if* you are careful about who or what has access to change those attributes.

For example:

- If someone can change tags on the key, they can remove the tag or change it's value, which opens up the key to account principal that has an IAM policy granting `kms:xyz` on that resource.
- If someone can change the IAM policy, policy attachments, etc., they might circumvent the tag-based control.

Tags (and other global and KMS-specific condition keys) can help here, as well. It would need a deeper dive that what we can do in this post, but as an example, you could give folks `ALLOW` for `Tag:*` / `Untag:*` IAM permissions on `Resource: '*'`, but also include a policy to DENY those same actions *if* the target resource already has the `kms-key-access-tag`.

If you use AWS Organizations and the KMS key is in an account that is **not** the Organization management / root account, Service Control Policies (SCPs) are even better, because they let you apply DENY rules (with or without conditions) to an entire account (including the account root user). With SCPs, you don't have to bother with checking existing policies to make sure you didn't miss anything because SCP DENY (or any DENY for that matter) always wins.

#### Be careful with `kms:*` permissions

Recommendation is to carefully consider whether you really want to give kms:* to 100 roles for the same key. Remember, if your key is deleted or its access policy is changed accidentally or maliciously, any data encrypted with that key is lost (or unavailable until you can re-activate the key).

Consider that - with the tag-based approach - you could create more than one managed IAM policy to cover different permission levels.

For example, maybe you have:

- `KMS-S3-Encrypt Policy` that grants `kms:GenerateDataKey` and/or `Kms:Encrypt` used for your IAM roles that write data to S3, but don't grant Decrypt because - hypothetically - they should never be reading from a bucket.
- `KMS-S3-Decrypt Policy` that gives `kms:Decrypt` for your backend data processing application that neds to read from S3.
- `KMS-S3-Key Admins Policy` grants `kms:*` and is attached only to the select few super-users that might need it in an emergency.